# J'en ai passé du temps à écrire toutes ces lignes

Tags: pronoms, en

Why have they put 'en' in the sentence. It means, "I spent time writing these lines". What role does 'en' play? What exactly does it mean here?

Answer (score 7):

A common usage of "en" is to refer to something that was mentionned just before, so in general, it makes sense to translate "en" by "it" in english.
For example "Du temps?. J'en ai passé à écrire toutes ces lignes." would translate to "Time? I spent a lot of it writing all these lines".

Considering "J'en ai passé du temps à écrire toutes ces lignes":

In that case "en" refers to "du temps" which sounds completely useless because it is already explicit in the sentence.
The goal here is to create a redundance to put a strong emphasis on "temps". The word "toutes" also adds emphasis.
The sentence could translate to something like: "That's a lot of time I spent writing all these lines!" to clearly show that the main focus is on the time spent.

What you said: "I spent time writing all these lines" would translate to "J'ai passé du temps à écrire toutes ces lignes" which is also grammatically correct but slightly different in meaning.

Answer (score 6):

"En" is redundant in this sentence as its antecedent is "du temps". This is an accepted redundance because it is the redundance itself that gives the sentence its special power of expression. It is not used only with the verb "passer" and it expresses a variety of notions that can be the dejection, or surprise and satisfaction, or awe of who is talking or a combination of those, and always  simply the emphasis of how large is a quantity referred to; these notions are motivated by the idea of the apparently excessive, or at any rate great, quantity of something that has been needed in achieving something or that has resulted from some process. It is used with various tenses.

- Il en aura **fallu** des années de travail pour construire ce barrage. (slight dejection (maybe) but essentially awe)
- Ils en ont **essayé** des marques de bière avant d'en trouver une qui leur plaise ! (emphasis on the large number)
- J'en ai **passé** du temps à écrire toutes ces lignes. (possible slight dejection (but not necessarily), awe)
- Eh bien ! Tu en **as** des images dans ta boite. ( insistence on the great number of the pictures owned, surprise)
- Il y en **avait** des gens sur cette plage ! (emphasis on the large number)

An important thing to keep in mind is that when speaking these sentences they will  come across to the interlocutor as having  the meanings explained above only if sentence stress is put on the verb or if there is an adverb modifying the verb on that adverb. The form to receive sentence stress and intonation has been put in bold type in the examples above. Dejection, awe and surprise are essentially in the intonation, which is unfortunatelly too difficult a subject for someone to be able to say anything useful in a few words; moreover, I fear I couldn't describe this particularity to any extent in a proper enough manner. Really, I see no better way of picking up the intonations than by listening to well spoken samples.

- Il en a **vraiment** passé du temps à écrire toutes ces lignes.

Comment: "only if sentence stress is put on the verb or if there is an adverb modifying the verb on that adverb" → This is so good you should highlight it somehow! +1

Comment: @Pasunclue You confirm that as part of your experience? (I think the bold type will be enough)

Comment: Absolutely. Not only part of what I hear, but part of what I do myself. The only other thing I could add is from my Quebecquer's perspective for your last example: «Y'en avait-**tu** du monde à la plage!», using a variation on the interrogative "tu" and putting the emphasis on that word. (But I know you're not interested in Canadian French that much...)

Comment: @Pasunclue I don't know if the French say that, it's unknown to me. It's not really a lack of interest, I'm curious about it but can't have to deep an interest. I find interesting for instance that French Canadians say "fin de semaine" instead of "weekend".

Comment: I meant the sentence I quoted should be highlighted somehow, not only its application in the examples.

Comment: @Pasunclue Yes, I got your point, but I don't feel like doing that, although I do share your     appreciation: it _is_ something to keep in mind. (glad you could confirm that, anyway)

Comment: @Pasunclue  — « Y'en avai*s*-tu du monde à la plage ! » se dit probablement sur les rives du St Laurent, du côté de Deauville ce sera plutôt : «  [Eh bien (dit donc) ! …] J'en ai vu du (beau) monde sur les planches ! »

Comment: @Personne Je suppose qu'alors l'emphase porte sur le verbe, non? Ce serait la situation décrite dans la réponse. J'avais mentionné un exemple où l'emphase porterait sur un autre type de mot pour élargir un peu le portrait (mais demeure conscient de la portée probablement locale de la tournure...)

Comment: @Pasunclue — Atelier théâtre : essayez de trouver un rôle qui met l’accent principal sur : « J'en | ai vu | du beau | monde | sur les planches ! » en ayant ou pas une accentuation secondaire (Inspiration de la Comédie-Française, du Théâtre de Boulevard et autre "happening", prosodie …)

Comment: @Personne Je confesse sans gêne le fait que je serais un piètre acteur. Je sais lire à haute voix avec une certaine emphase, mais quand j'entends des acteurs déclamer des fables de La Fontaine, je me rends bien compte que je ne suis guère talentueux. Mais tout de même... «J'en ai passé **du temps** à écrire toutes ces lignes»???? On dit ça à son patron pour expliquer qu'il va payer le gros prix pour toutes ces lignes?? Un peu tiré par les cheveux non? Ou bien quelque chose m'échappe complètement.

Comment: @Pasunclue — Parmi les nombreux patrons ou chefs de service qui m'ont supporté, au moins deux (archis compétents) se seraient amusés de la tournure formulées avec humour (second degré), en prévision du rendez-vous annuel de révision des salaires. Entendre comme réponse « Pas trop tôt ! » qui efface l'effort consenti est une autre histoire.

Comment: Le prix gros, québécisme pour « le prix fort » ; https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=le+gros+prix%2Cle+prix+fort&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cle%20gros%20prix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20prix%20fort%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cle%20gros%20prix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cle%20prix%20fort%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Personne C'est navrant de faire perdre leur temps aux gens comme ça…

Comment: Non, c'est humain, il suffit de l'accepter et de passer à autre chose :-)